# Identify Results form for virtual layers in QGIS keeps displaying wrong feature

Tags: qgis, identify, virtual-layer

When I load up a virtual layer and I use the Identify Results tool, it will display the correct information in the Identify Results panel, but in the feature form popup it will always display only the one feature (I haven't figured out which one, it isn't always the one at the top of the feature list).

In the example below, no matter which polygon I pick, the feature form will always show T1.

[image]

This is happening regardless of the complexity of the query, even if it's a simple SELECT id FROM table. And it happens whether I use the autogenerated feature form or drag and drop my own.

Can this be fixed? Is it a limitation of how virtual layers handles queries? Using QGIS 2.18.12.